# Windows 10, 'expo build:android\ fails with "Error: spawn /bin/cp ENOENT"

Tags: compilation, expo

After several hours of fighting this problem, I finally found a workaround.
Posting here so it might help someone until the issue is fixed.

When running `expo build:android` or `expo publish` task finish with error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
[00:46:48] spawn /bin/cp ENOENT
[00:46:48] **Error: spawn /bin/cp ENOENT**
    at notFoundError (..\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:11:11)
    at verifyENOENT (..s\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:46:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (...s\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:33:19)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Related to expo-cli issues:

- https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/328
- https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1839

Suggested solution to run `git bash` did not work, I also wanted to avoid installing node and all other npm packages on WSL.

`expo diagnostics`

```
  Expo CLI 3.18.6 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.16.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 1.22.0 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because the expo-cli code assumes that `/bin/cp` exits (found it thanks to https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/328#issuecomment-562809248).

Solution:

To make the /bin/cp available you can create a symbolic link to the bin folder of the git bash - it contains the required commands.
Make sure to create it in the same drive as the project you are trying to compile (i.e. if the path to your expo project is D:\projects\expo1, create the symbolic link in D:)

1. Install Git for windows (https://gitforwindows.org/)
2. Find the path to the 'Git for windows' installation path. (e.g. C:\Program Files\Git)
3. Open cmd as administrator
4. Go to the root folder of the drive of which your expo project resides. (e.g. D:)
5. Run: `mklink bin <git for windows path>\usr\bin` (e.g. mklink /d bin "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin")

Hope it helps to someone out there, Good luck!